# how to align input with the last label line with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, label

I've made a bootstrap form, and i want align my input with the last text line of his refferencial label:

this is my code:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date de début des soins:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Durée des soins:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
                            </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tibuakaw/q945k4eg/

how to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Please explain your question exactly

Comment: for simplicity, you could use a table layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for the answer to this:

You can do it with vertical-align: baseline
The label needs to be wrapped in an inline-block element and the line-height needs to be set on the outer container. In the sample below, the first one is using divs, the second is using a table.

```css
.row {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* For demonstration purposes */

.label {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <span class="label" style="white-space: normal;">Date de début des soins:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
</div>
<div class="row" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <span class="label" style="white-space: normal;">Durée des soins:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
</div>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
      <span class="label">Date de début des soins:</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td><span class="label">Durée des soins:</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9x3wote/

Answer (score 0):

A table layout is a quick way of doing it

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Date de début des soins:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Durée des soins:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g8m16v48/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">                      
                     <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Date de début des soins:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">                            
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">Durée des soins:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
                        </div>
                        </div>                              
                    </div>
```

Comment: @Takarii not the same but different bootstrap classes.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is your solution and how does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.control-label{

float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date de début des soins:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Durée des soins:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name">
                            </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```